# How to make user hover for two sec before slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, slide

I have a working code below that does `slideDown` functionality, but I want the user to hover for 2 sec at least before it should slide down. If the user doesn't hover for 2 sec it should not slide down.

I had tried the delay but it still fires even though I haven't hovered on the link for 10 sec.

Here is my code below and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/zsdgjsz7/2/) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".item-content").hide();

    $(".item-show").on("mouseover", function() {
        $(this).delay(10020).hide().parent('p').next(".item-content").delay(1520).slideDown( "slow" );
    });

    $("span.close-icon").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent('.item-content').slideUp('slow').parent().find('.item-show').show();
    });
});

$("div.previewCardPageClose").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent('.previewCard-content').slideUp('slow').parent().find('.previewCard-showhide').show();
});
```

Comment: setTimeout + clearTimeout + mouseout event will do the job.

Comment: setTimeout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: Aside that Kevin B is correct; make *very* sure you understand what a horrible UX this must be for a user. 10 seconds is *ages* in UI land so you better have a darn good reason to even want this.

Comment: Yeah it's a good way to get a user to leave your page quickly, or contact you about a "bug".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roXon/zsdgjsz7/8/)***

You need (beside the comments in code) to use `.on()` method for dynamically generated elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var timeo = null;

   $(".item-content").hide(); // Hide all!!!

    $("body").on("mouseenter", ".item-show", function() { // Use rather mouseenter!

        var $that = $(this);           // Store the `this` reference
        clearTimeout( timeo );         // Clear existent timeout on m.Enter 

        timeo = setTimeout(function(){  // Before setting a new one
            $that.hide().closest('p').next(".item-content").slideDown( "slow" );
        }, 2000);

    }).on("mouseleave", ".item-show", function(){   // mouse leaves? Clear the timeout again!
        clearTimeout( timeo );
    });  

    $(".close-icon").on("click", function() {
        var $itemB = $(this).closest(".item-b");
        $itemB.find(".item-content").slideUp();
        $itemB.find(".item-show").show();
    });

});
```

Comment: #Roko-thank you.. I just treplaced mine with urs its breaking . Here is .my fiddlehttps://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/zsdgjsz7/2/

Comment: @user244394 fixed a typo `Timeout` with "m". You did not closed your brackets in your demo :)

Comment: after adding  your everything is open by default and seems broken :(

Comment: @user244394 updated answer and demo. Please try now to incorporate the clicks again using `.on()`

Comment: The problem with targeting the `body` tag for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, is that the mouse never leaves the body...

Comment: @vince. Wrong. `"body"` is just the **static** element handler for the **dynamic** delegated `.item-show` - Look closely :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I understand what you're going for, but it is wiser to target an element closer to the dynamic element.  Hence why I have used `$('#data')` in my answer.  Does the `mouseleave` handler actually fire in your example?

Comment: @vince updated my answer and demo to show you after 2s, when it opens how to trigger the close X button click. Give it a try. Dynamic event delegation is not exactly needed in your case, since you append your dynamically generated elements before assigning events. But it's best to use them. Just in case.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Interesting -- I made my comment based on an assumption.  Looks like I was wrong.  Didn't realize it could work that way.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` functions.  Something like this should work:

```
var timer;

$("#data")
    .on("mouseover", ".item-show", function() {
        var el = $(this);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
                el.closest('.item-b').find(".item-content").show('slidedown');
        }, 10000); })
    .on('mouseout', ".item-show", function() {
        clearTimeout(timer); });
```

**EDIT**:  Having looked at the jsFiddle you posted in a comment, it seems that you will also need event delegation in order to make this work.  I have updated my answer accordingly. (edited fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/zsdgjsz7/4/)

**EDIT 2**: I re-read your question and I believe I now understand what you're going for.  Please see my updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zsdgjsz7/9/

Comment: @Venice - I tried to incorporate urs with my example in Fiddle  fiddlehttps://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/zsdgjsz7/2/  It didnt work :(

Comment: @user244394 Edited my answer, having seen your jsFiddle.